# Why does printing out an array of char result in random characters?

Tags: arrays, c, printf, c-strings

I am trying to learn programming and am doing some random questions and tasks. The task is to write out the last three characters of a string and this is what I've come up with. Please do not solve this for me, I am asking about my output/result not for anyone to do the problem solving for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int func(char *input_1, char *input_2) {
    char last_three_digits_1[3]; // define two arrays that hold the last three characters
    char last_three_digits_2[3];

    int x = 0;
    for(int y = strlen(input_1) - 4; y < strlen(input_1) - 1; y++) {
        last_three_digits_1[x] = input_1[i];
        x++;
    }

    x = 0; // repeat for the second string
    for(int z = strlen(input_2) - 4; z < strlen(input_2) - 1; z++) {
        last_three_digits_2[x] = input_2[i];
        x++;
    }


    printf("last3_1: %s, \nlast3_2: %s\n", last_three1, last_three2); // this seem to access random memory because it outputs "abc" followed by random "-???" or "-????" or "-?2?2". Same for the second array.

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[] ) {
    if(argc == 3) { // needs to be two strings. E.g: "abcd efghi"
        if(strlen(argv[1]) >= 3 || strlen(argv[2]) >= 3) { // if any of the strings are less than 3 in length, e.g. "ab wadnkwa" then do not proceed.
            func(argv[1], argv[2]); // send the user input to the function
        }

        return 0; // maybe redundant
    }

    return 0; // return 0 for failure
}
```

Comment: `strlen(argv[1]) >= 3`  and `i = strlen(text1) - 4` - when `strlen(argv[1])` is `3`, then `i` is `-1`.

Comment: you should start with checking the arguments to your function e.g. you assume text1 is at least 4 chars so check if it is like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char last_three1[3]; // define two arrays that hold the last three characters
char last_three2[3];
```

You need space to hold `\0` char, because `%s` expects `char*` to be `\0` terminated.

```
char last_three1[4]; 
char last_three2[4];

….
last_three1[x] = '\0';
x = 0; // repeat for the second string
for(int i = strlen(text2) - 4; i < strlen(text2) - 1; i++) {
    last_three2[x] = text2[i];
    x++;
}
last_three2[x] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the if statement

```
if(strlen(argv[1]) >= 3 || strlen(argv[2]) >= 3)
```

means that the length of one of the strings can be less than 3. In this case the function `func` can invoke undefined behavior.

It seems you mean

```
if(strlen(argv[1]) >= 3 && strlen(argv[2]) >= 3)
```

Otherwise you need in the function `func` to make a check whether a string has length greater than or equal to 3 before outputting its last three characters.

If a string has exactly three characters then for example in this loop

```
for(int i = strlen(text1) - 4; i < strlen(text1) - 1; i++)
```

the variable `i` can have an implementation defined value as for example -1 and as a result this expression `text1[i]` invokes undefined behavior.

The return type `int` of the function does not have a meaning.

Pay attention to that if you are using the format `%s` to output a character array using `printf` then the array shall contain a string that is a sequence of characters terminated with the zero character `'\0'`.

So neither the if statement in main nor the function itself makes a sense.

To output last three (or any other number) characters of a string there is no need to create an auxiliary array. It can be done much simpler.

For example

```
void func( const char *text1, const char *text2, size_t n )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( text1 );
   
    if ( !( n1 < n ) ) text1 += n1 - n;

    size_t n2 = strlen( text2 );

    if ( !( n2 < n ) ) text2 += n2 - n;

    printf( "last%zu_1: %s, \nlast%zu_2: %s\n", n, text1, n, text2 );
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
func( argv[1], argv[2], 3 );
```

Using such a declaration of the function you can output any number of last characters of two strings. Also take into account that the function parameters have the qualifier `const` because the passed strings are not changed within the function.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func( const char *text1, const char *text2, size_t n )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( text1 );

    if (!( n1 < n )) text1 += n1 - n;

    size_t n2 = strlen( text2 );

    if (!( n2 < n )) text2 += n2 - n;

    printf( "last%zu_1: %s, \nlast%zu_2: %s\n", n, text1, n, text2 );
}

int main( void )
{
    func( "Hello", "World", 3 );
}
```

The program output is

```
last3_1: llo,
last3_2: rld
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C are terminated with a single zero byte.

You're not zero-terminating the strings, so `printf` doesn't know where to stop printing (and you're lucky your program doesn't outright crash).

I'd refactor things like this, so you have a single function that simply copies the three last bytes and zero-terminates the string:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// out must be an array that can hold 4 bytes
// in must be >= 3 characters; otherwise this function returns non-zero
int get_last_three(char *out, const char *in) {
  int len = strlen(in);
  if (len < 3)
    return -1;
  for (int i = len - 3; i < len; i++) {
    *out = in[i];
    out++;
  }
  *out = 0; // Zero-terminate
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char out[4];
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (get_last_three(out, argv[i]) == 0) {
      printf("last3_%d: %s\n", i, out);
    }
  }
}
```